# PCB Connector Footprint - Through Hole Diameter - IPC Standard and Datasheet Specification

Tags: pcb, connector, footprint

I'm creating a footprint for a molex PCB connector ([Drawing PDF here](https://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/1722981108_sd.pdf)).

The datasheet contains a section for PCB layout.

[image: PCB Layout]

For the connector leads it states a diameter of 1.02mm with 0.04mm tolerance.

I understand that the IPC standards provide guidance on selecting a hole size based on the component lead size.

1. Should I assume that the diameter measurement in the drawing is the hole size, which should be followed directly, without increasing it? (or is it the lead diameter size)
2. What does the box just below the 1.02mm measurement mean (the one containing [0.10|A|B|C])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. yes
2. That box specifies the tolerances on locations ABC shown as DIM "A",[B],[C]"C"

... don't ask where are D,E

Do they still teach drafting in 1st yr Eng?

Comment: I see, the diameter has a tolerance of 0.04mm, the position has a tolerance of 0.10mm, and the "16 Places" means that it applies to every lead.  Thanks.